# Using cwac-endless adapter with existing/custom AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, adapter, commonsware-cwac

I'm currently using what I assume is a common pattern in Android, of fetching data from a network using various AsyncTasks, and updating a simple ArrayAdapter on completion using an interface callback mechanism.

cwac-endless is reasonably easy to plug in to add pagination type scrolling, aside from the fundamental issue that it assumes it will handle running the background task for you.  Does this mean I basically have to rip up all my AsyncTask classes and associated interfaces, and move all the code from doInBackground into my EndlessAdapter's cacheInBackground?

Most solutions I've tried seem to end up duplicating much of the code already in cwac-endless, so I feel there must be cleaner solution to using this adapter with an existing AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cwac-endless is reasonably easy to plug in to add pagination type scrolling, aside from the fundamental issue that it assumes it will handle running the background task for you

Handling "running the background task for you" is most of the point behind the adapter.

> Does this mean I basically have to rip up all my AsyncTask classes and associated interfaces, and move all the code from doInBackground into my EndlessAdapter's cacheInBackground?

If you wish to use `EndlessAdapter` as it stands, yes.

You are certainly welcome to grab the code, modify `getView()` to not use its own `executeAsyncTask` and `AppendTask` and replace that logic with your own. However, pretty much every line of code in `AppendTask` is necessary for `EndlessAdapter` to work. And I have no idea how any endless construct would work with "custom AsyncTasks" *plural*, as there has to be a clear end to the work so that we know to show the new rows in the list and get rid of the pending `View`. Hence, you would still need to designate some `AsyncTask` of yours as playing the role of `AppendTask`, doing everything that you are presently doing *and* all of the logic in `AppendTask`. Whether that is simpler than just using the existing `EndlessAdapter` code base, I cannot say, as I do not know your code.

> I feel there must be cleaner solution to using this adapter with custom AsyncTasks?

You are the first person to ever raise the issue, and hence I have never considered it prior to typing in this answer. I will give it some thought and [may try to do some refactoring](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/issues/14) to help with your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply.

I say AsyncTasks plural to highlight the fact there are multiple task/adapter pairs that would need to be reconstructed, not necessarily that I'm trying to use more than one task to populate the adapter.

As I mentioned, I have already begun looking at ways of giving more control over AppendTask, so if I arrive at something useful I'll be happy to submit it.  Just wanted to be sure there wasn't already an obvious way I wasn't seeing.